# [coDisplay wordpress posts does not work

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following code in the wordpress theme I created and it does not display anything despite there are 2 posts active! What is wrong?

```
else : 
echo 'No content found';

endif;

?>
```

Files in theme currently are only index.php, header.php, footer.php and style.css as we are justg beginning to build it

Instead of the error message it prints one word "Home" and home is not even the title of any of the posts? What is wrong?

Thanks
Tim

Comment: What following code? Please amend question to include the code.

Comment: Sorry this is the code [code] if ( have_posts() ) :
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  // Your loop code
  the_title();
 endwhile;
else :
 echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
[/code]

Comment: Can you amend your question to include the code you provided in the comment and also include a list of your theme's _.php_ files?

Comment: sorry have no clue how to make the code show up here